# Width of the response in command prompt in windows

Tags: windows, terminal, formatting, command

The command prompt help and other output from screen when copied to some other text format have width issues. MANWIDTH is used in linux to change this width. Is it just an environmental variable? How to widen or dump the formatted output to a text file?

Comment: `MANWIDTH` only applies to `man`. You can use [`fold`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#fold-invocation) to wrap lines.

Comment: Oh wait, Windows. `fold` is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Command-prompt help is preformatted (doesn't grow with increasing window-width).  There's a console-API which could return this information, but the preformatted help-text does not use that.